# iframe content showing on local test, but not live on web

Tags: html, css, iframe

I want to display a list of the latest reviews on my site in pages on my site. I created latest_reviews.htm for the list and uploaded it and the other page has an IFRAME.  It works when I test with the page on my computer and the source list on the web.  When I move the other page to the web, the list no longer appears. I've tested in mozilla and chrome, with and without an ad blocker.

The other page has:

````
<iframe src="http://festivale.info/film/latest-reviews.htm" WIDTH="100%" max-width: 255px frameborder="0" scrolling="yes"></iframe>```

The latest reviews page is simple HTML with a style (if that makes any difference)
<style>
body {padding: 0; margin: 0; display: table;
text-align: left;
background-color: #ffffcc;
}
p {
font-family: ARIAL, VERDANA, HELVETICA, "MS SANS SERIF", SANS-SERIF;
font-size: 85%;
}
</style>

For example:  https://festivale.info/filmrvu2022/where-crawdads-sing-2022_moviereview.htm
````

Answer (score 0):

Your site is using HTTPS, but you are trying to load the IFRAME with an HTTP src, Chrome blocks this (and other browsers too) for security reasons.

You can see this buy opening the Developer Tools (Chrome) - Clicking the Console tab and the error message is right there:

`Mixed Content: The page at 'https://festivale.info/filmrvu2022/where-crawdads-sing-2022_moviereview.htm' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure frame 'http://festivale.info/film/latest-reviews.htm'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.`

You should load the IFRAME with an HTTPS source to fix the issue.